# Connecting to a network without WEP security using ManagedWifi APi

Tags: c#, xml

I am using ManagedWifi API to write an application

the example in  http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41381#213980 gives us a view of how to connect to a SSID with WEP security .

I would like to have to some pointers as to what would need to change if we need to connect to a known SSID "without" WEP security ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that that example uses WEP is because the used profile uses WEP.

A WLANProfile should follow [the schema explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706965%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  A number of sample WLANProfiles can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369853%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

A WLANProfile for an open network should look more or less like this (can't test it right now)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>{0}</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>{0}</name>
        </SSID>
        <nonBroadcast>false</nonBroadcast>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>manual</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>open</authentication>
                <encryption>none</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

With `{0}` being the SSID you want to connect with